# Azure SDK for Python whoami call to get currently signed in user

Tags: python, azure

I'd like to ask Azure for the details of the currently signed in user programmatically within a Python program. The program might run from the command line or within Azure batch.

Is there way to do the same thing as the azure cli does with `az ad signed-in-user show`, but through the Azure SDK for Python?

UPDATE:

Based on Gaurav's help and pointer to the [Microsoft Graph Python Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core), I tried the following:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from msgraphcore import GraphSession

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(
    exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True,
)

account_name = "mydatalake"
container_name = "test"

service = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/",
    credential=credential
)

container_client = service.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for i, blob in enumerate(blob_list):
    print("\t" + blob.name)
    if i >= 9: break

scopes = ['user.read']
graph_session = GraphSession(credential, scopes)
result = graph_session.get('/me')
print(result.json())
```

I successfully get back blob names from a storage account. But it fails when it gets to the GraphAPI part with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/src/azure_whoami.py", line 58, in <module>
    result = graph_session.get('/me')
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/msgraphcore/middleware/options/middleware_control.py", line 24, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/msgraphcore/graph_session.py", line 41, in get
    return super().get(self._graph_url(url))
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/msgraphcore/middleware/middleware.py", line 26,
in send
    return self._middleware.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/msgraphcore/middleware/authorization.py", line 16, in send
    request.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self._get_access_token())})
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/msgraphcore/middleware/authorization.py", line 33, in _get_access_token
    return self.credential.get_token(*self.scopes)[0]
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/default.py", line 138, in get_token
    token = self._successful_credential.get_token(*scopes, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/decorators.py", line 27, in wrapper
    token = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...snip...]/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/azure_cli.py", line
58, in get_token
    raise error
azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: Please run 'az login' to set up an account
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the instructions provided [`here`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core), you would first need to install the appropriate SDKs (`msgraphcore` and `azure-identity`).

After that your code would be something like (again taking from the same link)

```
# import modules
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential, DeviceCodeCredential
from msgraphcore import GraphSession

# Configuring credentials
# Added UsernamePassword for demo purposes only, please don't use this in production.
# ugly_credential = UsernamePasswordCredential('set-clientId', 'set-username', 'set-password')

device_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(
    'set-clientId')

# There are many other options for getting an access token. See the following for more information.
# https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/

# get data
scopes = ['user.read']
graph_session = GraphSession(device_credential, scopes)
result = graph_session.get('/me')
print(result.json())
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I want. They've left the hard part as an exercise for the reader. I haven't managed to get a credential that can successfully open a GraphSession. I thought I could use `credential = DefaultAzureCredential()`, but that seems not to work.

Comment: I saw a question yesterday about credentials not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165101/azure-chainedtokencredential-fails-after-password-change. Please see if this is the case for you as well. HTH.

Comment: Where do I get a clientId that will work with DeviceCodeCredentials?

Comment: If you have created an application in Azure AD, the client id is the application id of that application. Go to Azure Active Directory in Azure Portal --> App Registrations --> Find your application --> You can see the id in overview tab.